# How to loop regex re.match for invalid user input?

Tags: python, regex, loops, input

If a user types something invalid, how can I have this repeat "Please provide some info:" until they provide valid input instead of exiting at the end?

```
input_str = raw_input("Please provide some info: ")
if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", input_str):
    print "Error! Only letters a-z allowed!"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: use a `while not` instead of an `if not` and replace your `sys.exit()` with the `input_str` assignment line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just re assign your input_str

replace `sys.exit()` with `input_str = raw_input("Please provide some info: ")`

and wrap this in a while loop

```
while not re.match("^[a-z]*$", input_str):
    print "Error! Only letters a-z allowed!"
    input_str = raw_input("Please provide some info: ")
```

or if you prefer to keep your same setup you can just use a while True with a break.

```
while True:
    input_str = raw_input("Please provide some info: ")
    if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", input_str):
        print "Error! Only letters a-z allowed!"
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You're the same guy who just helped me with a MySQL question. Thanks again, man!

Comment: @kittenparade haha awesome :) glad I could help. If you have any more questions feel free to ask :) I'll throw ya a +1 too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
input_str = raw_input("Please provide some info: ")
while not re.match("^[a-z]*$", input_str):
    print "Error! Only letters a-z allowed!"
    input_str = raw_input("Please provide some info: ")
```